# What cable does my laptop display use?

Tags: cable

I recently took apart my old HP laptop to see what was in it, and I want to use the display as another screen in my house. The cable that went into the motherboard was brand new to me, so I went to the first place that came to my mind for help identifying it - Stack Exchange! My laptop is an HP G62-407DX.

[image: Cable Image.]

Comment: I don't know the name of it, but this article might be of use: http://www.afiata.com/circuit-diagram-laptop-lcd-display-to-vga-interface-project/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking LCD modules will use LVDS serial for data on a SMT crimp connector (single row for use with ribbon cable) and are usually 20, 30 or 40pin straight contact with polarity and lock snaps. The type in the image is also angled. The connectors don't follow any kind of standard and are made differently by each manufacturer. There are a few very common connectors and serial signaling on LCDs are usually the same with the same amount of pins which results in many being interchangeable.

Comment: Are there any adapters for LVDS to HMDI? I want to replace the motherboard and the one I have only has HDMI.

Comment: @Jared Gizersky Absolutely. The process of wiring it and matching up with the LCD controller is non-trivial however. I've only personally done something similar to this by using a monitors control board on a TV and swapping lcd modules with similar monitor models.

Comment: I'm not the most "techy" person, so can you please elaborate on what you mean by "wiring it up"? I am using a raspberry pi as the new "processor", so I have no idea how I would wire something like that up, and why I would wire it up.

Comment: @Jared Gizersky By wiring it up I mean finding a connector that you can actually use on a circuit board or by stripping the leads.

Comment: The LCD controller is the motherboard, right? I am taking that out, so that is why I need an adapter.

Comment: @Jared Gizersky The terminology here is used inconsistently especially by sellers but what I meant was the board physically attached to the LCD panel. It has a controller chip on it many of which have similar input but not all.